# Edge case in my code that i need help to fix

Tags: c

For some reason I can't format the code as code but here it is

I have it set to that the miles are /500 +1 so i get how many times 500 is in that and use that to calculate shipping cost. The test cases are:

1.5lbs, 200 miles - 1.5

5.6, 1200 - 11.10

1.0, 2500 - 7.50

8.5, 12345 - 133.75

12.8, 345 - "sorry..."

All codes work but test case 3 which results in 9.00 instead of the expected 7.50 and I need help figuring out how to get it to work.

Like I said for some reason stackover flow won't let me post the code

[image]

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the code. What reason was given for not being able to include it?

Comment: Corrected link to the image of the code.
Corrected english syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question well but I think the main problem you are facing is you are trying to find how many multiples of 500 are in a number and an easier way that handles all the special cases could be as follows.

```
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    // ...
    int ship = ceil(miles / 500.0); // note 500.0 to cast the operation to double
    // ...
}
```

So in case of miles is divisible by 500 it will result in an integer number that doesn't have to add 1 to it else it will result in a floating-point number which will be rounded to the higher integer number.